# How to detect a TOUCH event with another finger while an ACTION_MOVE is in process

Tags: android, event-handling

I am developing a game and I need to be able to detect that one finger is performing a MOVE while posibly another finger can TOUCH another part of the screen.

With the following code I am able to detect both the ACTION_MOVE (on certain region of the screen) and the ACTION_DOWN

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    final int dest_x = (int) event.getX();
    final int dest_y = (int) event.getY();

    onTrackPad = dbSettings.TRACK_PAD.contains(dest_x, dest_y);

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (onTrackPad) 
            {
                //move character 
            }         
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // Fire bullets 
            break;
    }
    //The event was consumed
    return true;
}
```

The problem is that I am not able to move and fire at the same time (I need to stop moving in order to fire and viceversa)

I am aware that [Android can handle multi-touch events](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi.html) but have not figure it how to use that to be able to process these events and the same time so that the player can move and fire at the same time

I have also try using the `getActionMasked` without any luck

Comment: isn´t your MotionEvent storing all the multytouch information?? https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi.html

Comment: @eduyayo you just included the same link as the one I provided could you provide me with a more detail answer (not a comment) Thanks

Comment: You need to execute moving and firing in a separate thread or it will interrupt the UI thread (if you don't do it already).

Comment: @Manu how will that be done ? I am currently not using threads to process the events, my View is also the touch listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading this question [Android MotionEvent.getActionIndex() and MultiTouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860879/android-motionevent-getactionindex-and-multitouch)

This is how I solved the problem

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int dest_x ;
    int dest_y ;

    p = event.getActionIndex() ;

    dest_x = (int) event.getX(p);
    dest_y = (int) event.getY(p);

    onTrackPad = dbSettings.TRACK_PAD.contains(dest_x, dest_y);

    action = event.getActionMasked() ;

    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (onTrackPad) 
            {
                //move character 
            }         
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // Fire bullets 
            break;
    }
    //The event was consumed
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MotionEvent has all information about touches that you need. You can get number of touches by executing `event.getPointersCount()`, and try to check  `MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN` instead of `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`. To get coordinates of each touch you can use `event.getX(0)` and `event.getX(1)`, same is for `y`. If you have a case of `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` with 2 touches, you will receive all this information in your motion event.

Comment: ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN  was deprecated in API level 8.
Use ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK to retrieve the data index associated with ACTION_POINTER_DOWN.

I have tried this approach but is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.
when multiple pointers touches on the screen,system generates the action events.we can keep track of individual pointers with in motion event using pointer id. Pointer id persists across touch events and also allows to track individual pointer across entire gesture.

```
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            int index = event.getActionIndex();

            int pointerID = event.getPointerId(index);

            int action = event.getActionMasked();

            if(event.getPointerCount() > 1)
            {
                Log.i("TouchType ", "Multi Touch");
                for(int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++)
                {
                    performAction(action);
                }
            }else
            {
                Log.i("TouchType ", "Single Touch");
                 performAction(action);
            }

        return true;
        }


  public void performAction(int action){
     switch(action)
    {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN : 
        Log.i("OnTouch ", "Pressed");

         // Fire bullets 
    break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
        Log.i("OnTiouch", "move");
        //move character 
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
        Log.i("OnTiouch", "Up");
    break;
    default:
        Log.i("OnTiouch", "None");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have already solve this problem with the code provided in my own answer